# How to control a built-in ribbon in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

For example, one of the things I want to customize is "Font>Borders>Line Style" being dotted line by default instead of solid line. How can I do this?

I want these customizations set at the start-up of each excel session or permanently, which will help speed up my work. I am thinking to change the default programmatically via vba. But not sure if there is any object model allows me to access the built-in ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own XML file with code that will customize your ribbon and create a relationship between this file and the Excel spreadsheet. There is a tool called CustomUIEditor which helps you with this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to customize built in ribbon tabs via vsto addins. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608593.aspx). I haven't tried it myself, but perhaps you can do something with the Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers?